# Polynomial time user pairing algorithm

Tags: algorithm, computer-science

i have a problem . Consider users with different weights which  depends on present channel .i.e. if the channel is good weights are high. I had to pair the users in such a way that total weight of the system should be maximum. I will elaborate this. Consider 4 channels and 8 users , now i have to place the paired users in each channel such that sum total of weights is maximum and all users are to be paired. Please suggest some polynomial time algorithms other than optimal(brute force) which becomes complex when number of users are large,which would be of great help to me.

Thanks and regards,
srinu.

Comment: This sounds pretty similar to the "stable marriage problem" (and even closer to its less-known relative, the "weighted matching problem").

Answer (score 1):

Vladimir Kolmogorov published [Blossom V: a new implementation of a minimum cost
perfect matching algorithm](http://pub.ist.ac.at/~vnk/papers/BLOSSOM5.html) in 2009 which provides a polynomial algorithm for the "problem of computing a perfect matching of minimum cost in an undirected weighted graph."

Changing to maximum cost is trivial by changing the sign of your weights.

This algorithm has a worst case complexity O(n^3m) (but is often much faster for typical examples).  n is the number of nodes, and m the number of edges.  In your case I believe all n^2 edges are present, so the complexity is O(n^5).

There are faster algorithms if your graph is bipartite (e.g. users fall into two categories such as male and female where you must always match a male with a female) but I don't believe that is the case for you?

A software implementation of this algorithm is [here](http://pub.ist.ac.at/~vnk/software.html).

Comment: The resultant graph will look like complete bipartite graph where each user is mapped to every other user and i have to solve this problem such that once the mapped users will not be mapped agin with other users ..  Thanks for your valuable information . Could u please suggest me the algorithms for user pairing if my graph is complete bipartite graph.( apart from hungarian algorithm) because it is already used in research for scheduling ).